# Как сделать динамический диапазон дат в Экселе?

Tags: excel, libre-office

Добрый день. Есть две ячейки. В одну я заношу дату начала проекта (например, 18.09.2016), в другую заношу длительность проекта (например 12). Я хочу, чтобы эксель сгенерил ячейки "18.09.2016","18.10.2016","18.11.2016"... и так далее до 18.09.2017. Т.е. автоматически генерил диапазон дат на основании длительности проекта. Как это сделать?

Comment: Правильнее - до 17.09.2017, иначе 1 день уже выходит из периода в  12 месяцев

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Формулами.**

Исходные: *A1* - начальная дата, *В1* - длительность проекта **в днях**.

В *А2* формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A2)>$B$1;0;A1+1)
```

Протянуть формулу вниз.

Формулы строк, которые ниже требуемого диапазона дат, покажут 0 (ноль).

Нули можно скрыть:

закладка *Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Для_листа...*, снять галку отображения нулевых значений.

Если даты не используются в дальнейших вычилениях, вместо нуля можно выводить пустую строку:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A2)>$B$1;"";A1+1)
```

Для периода, заданного **в месяцах** или годах, нужно определить количество дней в периоде или последнюю дату.

Например, для месяцев полная формула для *А2*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A2)>ДАТА(ГОД($A$1);МЕСЯЦ($A$1)+$B$1;ДЕНЬ($A$1)-1);"";A1+1)
```

Если показывать только даты помесячно:

```
ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A2)>$B$1;0;ДАТА(ГОД($A$1);МЕСЯЦ($A$1)+СТРОКА(A1);ДЕНЬ($A$1)))
```

Для уменьшения вычислений определение последней даты лучше вывести в отдельню ячейку и в формулах ссылаться на нее. Вариант:

```
=КОНМЕСЯЦА(A1;B1-1)+ДЕНЬ(A1)-1

=ДАТАМЕС($A$1;СТРОКА(A1))
```

---

**Макросом.**

Исходные: *A1* - начальная дата, *В1* - длительность проекта **в месяцах**.

Диапазон вставки: столбец *Е* - порядковый номер, столбец *F* - дата.

Формируется список дат с шагом 1 месяц:

```
Sub PeriodDats()
Dim ArrDate()
Dim dStart As Date
Dim lPer As Long, i As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        dStart = .Cells(1, 1).Value ' начальная дата
        lPer = .Cells(1, 2).Value ' период в месяцах
        If dStart = 0 Or lPer < 1 Then Exit Sub ' нет исходных данных, выход

        dStart = DateAdd("m", -1, dStart) ' первая дата будет dStart+месяц

        ReDim ArrDate(1 To lPer, 1 To 2) ' задаем размерность массива

        For i = 1 To lPer ' в цикле заполняем массив
            ArrDate(i, 1) = DateAdd("m", i, dStart)
        Next i

        .Columns("E:F").ClearContents ' очищаем столбцы
        .Cells(1, 5).Resize(lPer, 2).Value = ArrDate ' даты на лист
    End With

    MsgBox "Полный порядок", 64, "ФОРМИРОВАНИЕ ПЕРИОДА"
End Sub
```

Comment: >>вписать две даты...- можно, но задача автора - динамический диапазон.=====.ДАТАМЕС забыл (ДАТАМЕС(A1;12)-1), привел вариант с КОНМЕСЯЦА. Эти две функции не работают в Excel-2003, которым еще многие пользуются. Функция ДАТА универсальнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но  выдает по дням, а мне хотелось бы по месяцам. т.е. октябрь 2016, ноябрь 2016 ...Надо, наверное, какое то условие выставить, убирающее ненужные дни

Comment: Добавил в ответ